# How do I omit certain build types from email notifications in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: email, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

To be sure if project is compiling "from scratch" we have nightly builds. Usually these builds are successful, so, mails about them are not very useful.

Also there is usual builds, which run after someone commit code into version control. As these emails contain commit message and changed files list, they are useful even for successful builds.

How can I filter out successful nightly emails while still send all usual? Preferably by CruiseControl.Net means.

Here is part of CruiseControl.Net `ccnet.config` configuration file:

```
<intervalTrigger name="FrequentPoll" buildCondition="IfModificationExists"  seconds="60"/>
<scheduleTrigger name="Daily" buildCondition="ForceBuild" time="$(DailyBuildStartTime)"/>
```

Possible clue - in `<exec>` nodes program executed can determine which trigger started build by checking environment variable `CCNetRequestSource`.

However, even if, say, `CCNetRequestSource` was available in `<email>` node, yet I found no way `<email>` node may use it.

Can someone help me?

UPDATE: Found related question - [CruiseControl.net Email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143425/198852)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your email publisher with a [conditional task](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Conditional_Task) (available since **version 1.6**), like so:

```
    <conditional>
      <conditions>
        <compareCondition>
          <value1>$[$CCNetRequestSource]</value1>
          <value2>FrequentPoll</value2>
          <evaluation>Equal</evaluation>
        </compareCondition>
      </conditions>

      <tasks>
        <email ... />
      </tasks>

    </conditional>
```

Pay attention to **$[$CC]** syntax when referencing built-in variables.

Comment: I get this error when I attempt to use `<email>` within a conditional task (as seen above):

`ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: This publisher can only belong to a project`